# Database context for sys.databases and sys.master_files

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that pulls information for a database from the following tables

1. sys.master_files
2. sys.databases
3. sys.filegroups

Currently, the context set is the specific database which I want to query about.
But if the database is in a mode such that `USE DB_NAME` doesn't work,
is it okay to use `USE master`?
Since I am adding a **where clause on the basis of `DB_NAME`** will `USE DB_NAME` versus `USE master` make any difference?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? If you cannot use the database for some reason, you cannot query tables from that database. You can always use 3 part names (e.g., mydb.sys.tables) to access system tables in a specific database. And sys.databases only exists in the master database.

Comment: The db(lets say dbx) is in restoring mode, so cannot do `use dbx`. But since I am accessing the above mentioned tables only, I want to know if using master versus using the db in the use db_name makes a difference because previously it was set to `use dbx`. `use master` also gives the same results.

Comment: sys.master_files is global, it contains a unified view of all databases' sys.database_files (more or less). Except for tempdb, where the size is not the current size but rather the size it is set to when we start SQL Server. If this isn't enough for you, then please add an example of what you ae doing in your query/script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query `sys.databases` or `sys.master_files`, you are always going to be querying the system view that lives in the `master` database, regardless of your current database context. This data is physically stored in the `master` database.

However, `sys.filegroups` is a system view for your current database, or the database you reference using a 3-part name. This data is **not** stored in `master` database, but in each individual database. For example, the following two queries are equivalent:

```sql
--Query 1
USE dbx;
SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups;
--Query 2
SELECT * FROM dbx.sys.filegroups;
```

If you need to access `sys.filegroups` for a given database, that database must be online & accessible so that your query can access the data stored in that database.

If your query says this:

```sql
USE MyData
GO
SELECT DatabaseName    = d.name,
       FileLogicalName = mf.name,
       FilegroupName   = fg.name
FROM sys.databases    AS d
JOIN sys.master_files AS mf ON mf.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN sys.filegroups   AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = mf.data_space_id;
```

The file group name is going to ONLY have filegroup names from `MyData`, not from every corresponding database. Only the rows for `MyData` will be correct, and everything else will have problematic data. It's essentially doing this:

```sql
SELECT DatabaseName        = d.name,
       FileLogicalName     = mf.name,
       MyDataFilegroupName = fg.name
FROM master.sys.databases    AS d
JOIN master.sys.master_files AS mf ON mf.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN MyData.sys.filegroups   AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = mf.data_space_id; --Notice the DB name here
```

If you want accurate data for every database, you can use something like [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/), and do something like this:

```sql
EXEC dbo.sp_ineachdb @command = N'SELECT DatabaseName    = d.name,
       FileLogicalName = mf.name,
       FilegroupName   = fg.name
FROM sys.databases    AS d
JOIN sys.master_files AS mf ON mf.database_id = d.database_id
JOIN sys.filegroups   AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = mf.data_space_id
WHERE d.database_id = DB_ID();';
```

The `sp_ineachdb` script is available for download as part of the [First Responder Kit on github](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main). You'll find that there are a number of additional parameters that can be used to control exactly which databases are queried (or skipped) by the procedure.

Comment: This is really helpful. A follow on question, I have an equality check between the data_space_id from sys.master_files and the sys.filegroups. Since sys.filegroups cannot make use of dbx in restoring mode, I understand it is fetching master info and hence this equality can give me wrong result if I try to get anything from the sys.filegroups table even if the data_space_id match.

Comment: @SonaliGupta, I'd updated my answer with some more details, which I think will help you better understand the usage, and how to query data across all databases